# ByRef / ByVal issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm in the process of watching some intro type videos on nodejs. I ran into a problem which i figured out but i want to understand the "why". Here is the original code which had the issue:

```
    var http = require("http");
    var express = require("express");
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    var controllers = require("./controllers");

    controllers.init(app);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

    app.set("view engine", "vash");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Every time i went to go use the body object off of the request, it would be undefined. My issue was `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`. So how did i fix it? I moved that line above `controllers.init(app);`.

So again i want to understand the problem here so i can prevent it in the future. Is it some type of byref/byval problem? All the other changes i made to the app object after i pass it into the controller seem to work. Can anyone explain whats going on here and how to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

express creates a pipeline (based on connect middleware).  Essentially, each middleware chains to the next one by calling the `next()` callback and it keeps things simple by just stacking them in the order that they're passed to `app.use()` in your code.  Controller handlers are (normally) the exception to this in that they rarely call `next()` but instead end the chain by calling `res.end()` after performing some operation on the output stream (in your code you might not call `end()`, but other methods like `render()` and `send()` call it internally).

Comment: thanks. So in summary to prevent it make sure you call res.end() (which the sample i was following didn't do) in your controller or make sure you do everything to app object that you need to do before you pass it into the controller?

Comment: Well, again there's no requirement to directly call `.end()`, as there are many functions which do so under the hood.  The better rule of thumb is to declare your middleware in the order you want them executed, and generally routes go after everything else except (by convention, not necessity) error handling middleware